# how to write rspec test for Sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sunspot

After running test i revised coverage of ones.
One of the things that i don't know how to write test for is this:

```
 def index_advt
    Sunspot.index(advt) if advt
  end
```

Will there be any clues ?